# Drawing a X,Y chart with reversd X axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, latexmk

I have the following dataset:

```
X= 130, 65, 45, 22, 14, 10
Y= 1.8, 1.5, 1.2, 1.1, 0.9, 0.8
```

First of all, the code that I wrote looks very strange:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={My Chart},
        xlabel={X axis},
        ylabel={Y axis},
        ymin=0, ymax=2,
        xmin=0, xmax=140,
        ytick={1.8,1.5,1.2,1.1,0.9,0.8},
        xtick={10,14,22,45,65,130},
        legend pos=north west,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
    ]

        \addplot[
            color=blue,
            mark=square,
        ]
        coordinates {
            (0,0)(1,1)(2,4)(3,9)(4,16)(5,25)(6,36)(7,49)(8,64)(9,81)(10,100)
        };
        \legend{Data 1}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It will be rendered so:

[image]

I want to show a down-trend, so I guess it is essential that the X-axis is reversed, but I don't know how. This is the chart I ideally try to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x dir=reverse]
\addplot+ coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)(2,4)(3,9)(4,16)(5,25)(6,36)(7,49)(8,64)(9,81)(10,100)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph sloping down]

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't provide the document class you used. I use `standalone` as an example. This looks weird, kind of want to know the actual application. However, this is the way to do that.

> There is actual a easier way, using option `x dir=reverse`:

```
\documentclass[border=0.618cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={My Chart},
    xlabel={X axis},
    ylabel={Y axis},
    ymin=0.5, ymax=2,
    xmin=0, xmax=140,
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    x dir=reverse
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
] coordinates {
    (130,1.8)(65,1.5)(45,1.2)(22,1.1)(14,0.9)(10,0.8)
};
\legend{Data 1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Labelling the ticks with values that they are not will probably cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't realise it at the beginning.

Comment: @hpekristiansen And my approach was actually wrong, you have the correct answer.